# Parse a string in C++ using char delimiter but keep repeatable chars as delimiter inside each parsed substring (C++ STL)

Tags: c++, string, parsing

How can I parse this string:

```c++
std::string input_str = "-10-20--300---400";
```

into vector like this:

```c++
std::vector<string> output = { "-10", "20", "-300", "--400" };
```

using only C++ STL?

Comment: As an old C programmer I would use the `strspn`, `strcspn` functions from the C standard library. But it be done by hand if you do not like that...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Interesting. But what if I try solution with stringstream and getline and remove all empty elements in vector? If I have empty element in vector I simply add the delimiter string "-" at the begin of next element? I suppose there can be more effective solution...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you can answer all SO questions in this irony manner. Non-informative btw :)

Comment: I would argue that you need a better delimeter, and thus make the task closer to trivial.

Comment: Just replace the first occurrence of `-` with a space.  Then use `stringstream` on the adjusted string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: and what if the string already contains spaces?

Comment: @SergeBallesta We don't know that until the OP says what the string contains.  The example posted suggests no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to keep the (possibly multiple) separator(s) with their string. As I am too lazy to implement by hand what already exists in the standard library, and as the C standard library is explicitly included in the C++ one, I would use the `strspn` and `strcspn` functions to delimit the start and end point of the substrings and copy them to a vector.

A possible code could be:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

std::vector<std::string> parse(std::string input_str) {
    static const char delim[] = "-";
    std::vector<std::string> resul;

    const char *ix = input_str.c_str();
    const char *sentinel = ix + input_str.size();

    while (ix < sentinel) {
        const char *end = ix + strspn(ix, delim); // end of delim sequence
        if (end < sentinel) {                     // stop at end of string!
            end = end + strcspn(end, delim);      // go to next sequence
        }
        resul.insert(resul.end(), std::string(ix, end-ix));
        ix = end;
        if (ix < sentinel) ix += 1; // skip delimiter if not at end of string
    }
    return resul;
}
```

It gives the expected vector, and limits the copy and allocation of strings to the bare minimum. Maybe rather C-ish but should be correct C++ and Clang raises no warning...